# C GTK can't open Dialog again after closing via ESC

Tags: c, dialog, gtk, gtk3

I have a Dialog called `dlg_open` with an `btn_cancel_open` Button.
This  dialog is mapped at the Buton-Event and the `close` Event of the dialog to:

```
void on_btn_cancel_clicked (GtkWidget *widget, signal_map_data *smd) {
  #ifdef debug
    g_print ("-> on_btn_cancel_clicked\n");
  #endif
  gtk_widget_hide (gtk_widget_get_toplevel (widget) );
  gtk_widget_set_sensitive (smd->widg.wmw.wnd, 1);
}

void on_dlg_close (GtkWidget *widget, signal_map_data *smd) {
  #ifdef debug
    g_print ("-> on_dlg_close\n");
  #endif
  gtk_widget_hide (widget);
  gtk_widget_set_sensitive (smd->widg.wmw.wnd, 1);
}
```

This works fine. And here is how I open the dialog:

```
void on_btn_open_clicked (GtkWidget *widget, signal_map_data *smd) {
  #ifdef debug
    g_print ("-> on_btn_open_clicked\n");
  #endif
  gtk_widget_set_sensitive (smd->widg.wmw.wnd, 0);
  gtk_widget_show (smd->widg.wdow.dlg_open);
}
```

My problem is, that when I close the Dialog via keystroke `ESC`, I can't open it again, the main window looses its `sensitivity`, but the dialog doesn't appear, and at the console is a error message printed out:

```
Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_widget_show: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
```

When I close the dialog via the `cancel-button` itt works fine and I can reopen the dialog window.

Just a problem with the `ESC` .

But where/why?

**EDIT ACCORDING TO *andlabs* ANSWER: (!!UPDATED!!)**

I changed from a `on_dlg_close` function to a `response` management function:

```
void on_dlg_response (GtkDialog *dlg, gint r_id, signal_map_data *smd) {
  #ifdef debug
    g_print ("-> on_dlg_response\n");
  #endif
  switch (r_id) {
    case GTK_RESPONSE_DELETE_EVENT: {
      gtk_widget_hide (dlg);
      gtk_widget_set_sensitive (smd->widg.wmw.wnd, 1);
    }
  }
}
```

I've also added the `delete-event`:

```
gboolean on_dlg_delete (GtkWidget *widget, GdkEvent *event, signal_map_data *smd) {
  #ifdef debug
    g_print ("-> on_dlg_delete\n");
  #endif
  return FALSE;
}
```

[image: here]

This also works to close the dialog with ESC. But there is still the same problem that I can't reopen the dialog when I closed it via `ESC` Button with same error:

> -> on_dlg_response
>
> -> on_dlg_delete
>
> -> on_btn_add_clicked
>
> (main:16478): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid unclassed pointer in cast to 'GtkLabel'
>
> (main:16478): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_label_set_text: assertion 'GTK_IS_LABEL (label)' failed
>
> (main:16478): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_widget_show: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't want to connect to `close`; that's **only** for the Escape key being pressed. Instead, connect to `response` and check for known responses.

A GtkDialog is a GtkWindow; by default, when you click the Close button, it is destroyed. You will need to connect to `delete-event` to circumvent this behavior. (`gtk_dialog_run()` does this for you, which is why clicking the Close button on a dialog run with that function instead of manually doesn't destroy the widget. Of course, the override only takes effect for the duration of the call.)

Of course this means you'll need special handling for closing the dialog elsewhere. GtkDialog installs its own signal handler that issues a `response` with `GTK_RESPONSE_DELETE_EVENT` before going ahead with the deletion. If you just use `g_signal_connect()`, your code will run before that one will ever get a chance to run, and you'll need to have the dialog closing logic in two places. I don't know if you can use `g_signal_connect_after()` to put yourself in between GtkDialog's handler and the default, but it's worth trying. If that actually does work, then your `delete-event` could just be a `return TRUE;` and you do all your response handling in `response` instead.

Comment: checkout my edit, your solution is still no solution / doesn't remove my problem. Check again please

Comment: You did not read the entire answer. Simply changing to `response` isn't enough; you also have to override `delete-event`.

Comment: I'm using `gtk_builder_connect_signals` so what should I use instead of this?

Comment: In that case just add the `delete-event` signal to your .ui file in the same way the `response` signal is added, with the `after="yes"` attribute.

Comment: Oh I'm wrong, you need to return `TRUE`, not `FALSE`. Fixed the answer.